# Vue 3 + Typescript, union type with null in props declaration

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, union-types

I'm struggling with a "type-based" props declaration.

Here is the code:

```
type ValueType = string | number | boolean | null;

const props = defineProps<{
    selectedValue?: ValueType;
}>();
```

And the resulting error:

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Type '{ type: (StringConstructor | NumberConstructor | BooleanConstructor | null)[]; required: false; }' is not assignable to type 'Prop<unknown, unknown> | null'.
      Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
        Type '(StringConstructor | NumberConstructor | BooleanConstructor | null)[]' is not assignable to type 'true | PropType<unknown> | null | undefined'.
          Type '(StringConstructor | NumberConstructor | BooleanConstructor | null)[]' is not assignable to type 'PropConstructor<unknown>[]'.
            Type 'StringConstructor | NumberConstructor | BooleanConstructor | null' is not assignable to type 'PropConstructor<unknown>'.
              Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'PropConstructor<unknown>'.
```

I have found out that if I remove `null` from my union type `ValueType`, it solves the error. But what if I want to keep the `null` possibility ? Since this type comes from an old legacy code and is linked to an API response, I'd like as much as possible to be able to keep ValueType as it is for now.

Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: I'm not getting this error with your code, wondering if it's TS version related or something. Also would wrapping it in `PropType` help?

Comment: No idea why you're seeing this. I'm curious if `selectedValue?: ValueType | null` solves the issue, though (and remove `null` from `ValueType`, of course).

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Yes maybe I've just tried on the StackBlitz playground and I'm not getting any error too. I will try tomorrow to check versions on my project.

Comment: @tao Nice try ;-) but I already tried that and it produces the same error

Answer (score 0):

works fine for me. pls checkout the demo
https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9UsFOwzAM/ZUoJ5BQd9itdEOAdoADTDBxyqVr3dKRJlHijKLSf8dJtTIQ7BI5fi/Pz3Z6fm1MsvfAU565wjYGmQP0ZimUUE1rtEV2q1tWWToET2Z0iQ8EDwyhCq0cso4tBHdl5coxn81GsSiTIbRG5gh0y4IYSzuid4KzWUjNJpxfcHSkWDV1snNakateKEaFCyrbSLCPBhuqKHjKIhKwXEr9fh9zaD1cHPLFKxRvf+R3jkqnFKwtOLB76mXCMLc14Aivnh+go3gCW116SewT4BM4LX3wONJuvCrJ9hEvur2Lk21UvXGrDkG5Q1PBaGAOkS84TTpM/L/Wv+3Ok3l8J9RAUzxs6fdamcxVTbNHkom7wQ8D7CWXHjYhWjCHlmyxT6Z8uwVLwVZrCbmKKSkvj9durDaOHpVQNQrW4ZaRt2Cku0onWfK0PDs/+S/6Pmol3UAd/PwTwxcJTOaS